# Semantic UI rating component is not working in MVC 4 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, semantic-ui, rating

Most of the semantic ui component are working fine in my mvc application but rating component.
Rating appears but onRate function is not working. API documentation mentioned the jquery file should be loaded before semantic ui javascript.

Here is my code, I removed unrelated stuff

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rating.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div> what </div>
        <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="4"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.ui.rating').rating();
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used rating script and css file here. But I also tried semantic-ui script and css, and no success.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Ah, it is solved :D I tried "jquery-3.1.1.js" and when I want to check the console it was working. I think it was jquery version.

Comment: No.  Add you own answer explaining how you solved it (i.e. that `rating.js` requires a certain version of jquery) so that it helps others with the same problem solve it (and then accept it to close this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried "jquery-3.1.1.js" instead of "jquery-1.7.1.js" and rating.js was working.